# Getting Object back from an ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, stream, outputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

I have created an `ObjectOutputStream`

```
ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
stream.writeObject(myObject);
```

but how do I now convert this back into an `Object`, or even a `ByteArray`?

I've tried getting an `ObjectInputStream` like this

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = (ByteArrayOutputStream) myProcess.getOutputStream();
            
final ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()));
```

however I get a compile error saying it can't cast the `ObjectOutputStream` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`; yet there seem to be no methods on the `ObjectOutputStream` to get the data back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you do it

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
stream.writeObject(myObject);

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
Object o = inputStream.readObject();
```

Comment: Ah, yes, operating on the ByteArrayOutputStream instead of the ObjectOutputStream made the difference